# Understanding the content rule in the :before

Tags: html, css

How come the :before doesn't show anything when the content is empty, even though I set the height and width but when I enter some text in the content it shows that text?

CSS:

```
.a {
    background-color: cyan;
    height: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

.a:before {    
    /* This is the one that I change */
    content: "test";
    margin-left: -10px;
    background-color: red;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Because the [`:before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3abefore) pseudo element is displayed inline by default. Change that, and you'll see your square:

```
.a:before {
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/Va67f/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `display` property to `block` to display element

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/X2PFP/1/)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Have a look at the values and results for the content property.

"none: The pseudo-element is not generated"

Else the psudo elements display is inline. In your case I would use. Content: " " and display block.

Sorry. Formatting on my phone.